# Considerations for an Orthodox to teach in Reform/Conservative school

Tags: torah-study, reform-judaism, chinuch-education, conservative-judaism

There is a question for an Orthodox Jew to teach Torah in a Reform or Conservative school. What are the two sides of the question?

Does Rav Moshe Feinstein or other poskim in print address it?

Comment: Check out Aryeh Kaplan’s career on his Wikipedia page. Also, check out the letter penned to him by Rav Moshe Feinstein in IgrosMoshe OC i:98 relating to this

Comment: I would think that at opposite ends are 1) The possibility that an Orthodox person teaching halachot to non-observant kids may influences them to become observant vs. 2) Following the administration's objections to sticking strictly to non-observant and possibly anti-halachic philosophies and policies.

Comment: החזקת ידי עוברי עבירה, מוטב שיהיו שוגגין, and many more...

Comment: The two sides are: Kiddush Hashem vs Hilul Hashem.

Comment: I recall that Rav Zilberstein addressed this question. B”N if I can track down the source I’ll post it as an answer. His two sides were that the Orthodox teacher could draw the non-observant students and fellow teachers into Yiddishkeit, versus providing justification to other Orthodox families to send their children there, as “it can’t be that bad - they have Rabbi so-and-so on staff.” He concludes that the risk of the latter heavily outweighed the benefit of the former and ruled it forbidden.

Comment: IMO, the two sides of the question are a) how badly the poor guy needs that particular job to avoid bankruptcy, vs b) how much he knows he's compromising his beliefs by teaching there, having to start questions for the class with stuff like "David's driving to Wendy's on Shabbat to get a cheeseburger, should he use his cash to etc etc etc?"

Comment: DId anyone mention Mar'is Ayn (looks like he converted?).

Comment: The practial risks would be kind of funny...imagine getting fired from a Jewish school for keeping Yom Tov Sheni ;)